# How to make try/except loop until true

Tags: python, try-except

```
try:
    int(days)
except:
    print('Invalid input. A integer value was expected. Try again.')
    days = (input("Enter the number of days: ", ))
```

How do I make this try statement loop until true?

Comment: Use a `while` loop.

Answer (score 5):

I suggest putting your logic in the `try` block, and ONLY printing the error message on exception:

```py
while True:
    try:
        days = int(input("Enter the number of days: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid input. An integer value was expected. Try again.")
```

Also, you should never use a bare `except`. It is generally considered [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54948581/6298712).

Comment: Beat me to it by 20 seconds! :)

Comment: @Seth haha oof. RIP.

Comment: days isn't defined in yours either

Comment: Yes it is. The `try` block always runs.

Comment: Oh, I see it now.

Answer (score 4):

Wrap it in a `while` loop like this:

```py
while True:  # Don't exit until `break` is reached!
    days = input("Enter the number of days: ", )  # Move this here so `days` is always defined
    try:
        num_days = int(days)  # Save to a variable for later use
        break  # If the conversion succeeded, it will run this and exit the loop
    except ValueError:  # If the conversion failed (always specify a specific exception!), print the below:
        print('Invalid input. A integer value was expected. Try again.')
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a while statement and a variable to end it after int(days):

```
days = int(input("Enter the number of days: "))
done = False
while done == False:
    try:
        int(days)
        done = True
    except:
        print('Invalid input. A integer value was expected. Try again.')
        days = (input("Enter the number of days: ", ))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Quick Tip: `not done` is usually better than `done == False`!

Comment: This wouldn't work because `days` is unreachable. You're going to get a `NameError` on `try int(days)` because it hasn't yet been defined.

Comment: This isn't the whole code-just look at the other answers.

Comment: What? The other answers both safely define `days` before attempting to cast it to `int`. Your code does not do this.

Comment: Yes, I've removed my downvote. I downvoted because your code was going to crash, not because I didn't like it. Hope you don't take it personally.

Comment: nope, not at all, I just didn't understand.